# How to programmatically change UIView's frame inside an UIView Subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have a UICustomButton(subclass of UIButton) in the interface builder. I want change this button's frame inside UICustomButton.

I tried following code:

```
// make it 10 points wider and higher
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width + 10, self.frame.size.height + 10);
self.frame = newFrame;
```

in `awakeFromNib:, drawRect:`

none of them worked, the result is unchanged.

Comment: it is not clear _when_ (=after which event) you'd like to update the frame, but if it is related to the init procedure the `–initWithFrame:` or `–didMoveToSuperview` methods can be better places to do such thing – bear in mind, the auto-layout feature may override your frame value.

Comment: @holex I'd like to update the frame only once during the view's initiation. `initWithFrame:` doesn't work, because only 'initWithCoder:` gets called. Also, how to disable the auto-layout for this particular view?

Comment: you need to disable the auto-layout in the particular view's _superview_ instead - that may help on you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that! That's bad architecture!

A view should never change it's own frame. It's always the parent view resizing its children. 
If you detect you need another frame inside your view: send out a delegate call to the parent view and change the frame in there. the delegate method could look like this

```
- customButton:(UIButton *)button requestNewFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    button.frame = newFrame;
    // some storing method so you remember the frame on rotations and stuff
}
```

Just as a reminder: child views are always resized in

```
- (void)layoutSubviews //UIView
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews //UIViewController
```

That makes your code safe for different UIInterfaceOrientations and different devices.

Comment: who said the view cannot change itself...? no one, so... why would it be a bad architecture?

Comment: @fat's right. In order for a view to resize itself, it would need to know something about circumstances outside the view - which is bad compartmentalization, which is why we use objects.  Objects should just do things they know how to do, and not get information from outside.

Comment: @OwenHartnett, if you want to notify any class outside of an object, there are the pattern of _delegates_, post a simple nofitication via the _notification center_, or use _KVO_ on the class's certain property. the OOP's _encapsulation_ feature is also about hiding information from external objects. so, my question is still the same, how could it be a bad architecture?

Comment: @holex - all the circumstances you mention involve a trigger from an external class - here, the trigger is from the class itself polling an outside object to get information, then making decisions based on that.  That requires the class to know something about some external class. Maybe we're misunderstanding each other...why would a view want to resize itself?  Wouldn't there be information from an external object that would trigger it?

Comment: @OwenHartnett, you distort the problem a bit, it is not about _"why would a view want to resize itself?"_, the reason does not matter at all. if you've a button with a certain visual effect, probably you won't code that visual effect for every appearance of the button in its current owner class, you'd put such effects inside the button's class and reuse the button as many times as you want in the app. the button can change its title, colour, images _without_ notifying its owner; and the center, frame (etc) are in the same group. it's far away from any bad architecture; it is reasonable.

Comment: There are numerous instances where it's in the best interest for the view to resize itself and on the contrary there are numerous instances where the view should not resize itself. Point is don't be rigid and say that's bad architecture, bc in some cases--its not.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `awakeFromNib` nor `drawRect:` is appropriate.

You can change its frame in `layoutSubviews`, but you might run into trouble if your app uses auto layout.

Comment: If your app is using auto layout, look into the 'updateConstraints' method.

Comment: Just tried `layoutSubviews`, it doesn't work. I'm using storyboard, but didn't set up auto layout constraints explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it in viewDidLoad.  If you put it in a recurring method, it will increase in size each time it's called.

Comment: UIView doesn't have `viewDidLoad`, it belongs to `UIViewController`

Comment: sizing in viewDidLoad is bad. There is no way to react to screen size changes. Example: rotation!

Comment: Your custom button is a subclass of UIView, it's a subview of the viewController's UIView.  That's usually where last minute changes are placed when displaying views. Buttons are not usually resized on rotation, just relocated, but if you need to resize on rotation, you'd do that in your rotational code. Your code as you have it won't do rotation, as every time it's called it will just make the button bigger.